# Calculating a dynamic column in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
tourneys
--------
tourney_id
name
```

```
tourney_members
---------------
member_id
tourney_id
```

I want to select all the tourneys with the total number of members in that tourney.

I imagine the query would look something like the following. This of course causes a syntax error though.

```
SELECT t.*, (COUNT(*) FROM tourney_members m WHERE t.tourney_id = m.tourney_id) AS total FROM tourneys t
```

How can I end up with a result set of tourneys.tourney_id, tourneys.name, and total number of members as the third column?

Comment: Subquery is excess (moreover, it is synthactically wrong). Use JOIN, GROUP BY and COUNT().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply:

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(m.tourney_id) AS total
FROM tourneys t
LEFT JOIN tourney_members m ON t.tourney_id = m.tourney_id
GROUP BY t.tourney_id
```